# ActiveRecord update validates model's association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Given the relationship:

Library -> Books -> Category

Let's assume that category has some validations for instance:

```
validates :name, presence:true
```

If I run something like this:

```
Library.update(hash_with_all_attributes_from_library_to_category)
```

It will return true if all the library attributes are satisfied and ignore the category's validations.

why it happens? is there a better way to update all data except find one at time?

EDIT

I can't post the entire file but its a snippet

```
Class Question << ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :question_alternatives, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :question
  # couple of validations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :question_alternatives, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: -> (attributes) {
attributes[:text].blank?
```

}

And I check for the other relationships that I have the accepts_nested_attributes_for and the inverse_of

Comment: Are you using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`?

Comment: yes, for both of the relationships

Comment: Could you post all te model code you have plz?